# In ASP.NET, why would I use server controls over HTML helpers and vice versa?

Tags: asp.net, html

I am just starting to learn ASP.NET, and I'm confused by the difference between HTML helpers and server controls.

Why would I use

```
<asp:Label><asp:Label>
```

as opposed to

```
<%: Html.Label %>
```

It seems easier to use HTML helpers for getting POST data back, but server controls seem to offer a little more customization. Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Server controls are usually for when you are working with [ASP WebForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973868.aspx), while HTML helpers are a feature primarily used with [ASP MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc).

I understand you can mix them, but you are probably better off picking one and sticking with it.